# Defining a lot of table partition in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, erd

I've been defining exactly 121 table partitions on 10 MySQL tables using MySQL Workbench.
Each of those tables are used for logging use and its partitions are divided by every month from Jan 1st, 2013 up to 10 years from now.

I was just wondering if there is any way to copy & paste or to import partition definition at once without losing existing models.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no way in MySQL Workbench to transfer partition setups between tables or models, however it would make a good feature in certain situations. So if you like you can file a feature request to get this into WB (http://bugs.mysql.com).